# Keep unlogged meteor user while redeploying?

Tags: javascript, session, deployment, meteor

At the moment i'm using this.connection.id as unique identifier, but every time my application is deployed ( using `meteor-up` ) the client refreshes ( using `autoupdate` package ) the page and create a new subscription therefore creating a new `connection.id`.

My first `idea` i thought was to keep an unique id on the client, but:

- i'm afraid this could bring security issues?

  - one user could pretend to be another one by forging the "cookie"/localstorage?
- if the user open two tabs it would be perceived as only one session ?

  - ideally each tab should have it own session

Another idea would be to turn `autopublish` off, but that means mobile devices might keep and old client version for long time?

## client code

```
Meteor.subscribe 'my_channel', -> console.log "client subscribed"
```

## server code

```
Meteor.publish 'my_channel', -> 
    id = @connection.id

    console.log "user #{@connection.id} is on"

    @_session.socket.on 'close', ->

        console.log "user #{@id} is off"

Meteor.methods 

    hello: ->
        console.log "Hello! i know who you are! #{@connection.id}"
```